# XAML RadioButton Content string not being displayed at runtime

Tags: xaml

My XAML file contains a RadioButton. In the Visual Studio's XAML Designer I can see the display of the Content string for this RadioButton. However, when I run the application, the RadioButton is displayed in the GUI without the Content string "Disble E-mail Alerts from Dashboard". Following is the line in the XAML file which declares the RadioButton:

```
<RadioButton Height="16" Margin="30,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="DashboardDisableAlerts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="194">Disble E-mail Alerts from Dashboard</RadioButton>
```

I will really appreciate any help in helping debug why the Content string is not being displayed in the GUI at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: I would take a look at your code for anything that may be operating on the DashboardDisableAlerts (the RadioButton) variable. Your XAML looks correct.

Comment: Can you give us more of the layout, this doesn't really get me anywhere.

Comment: Is this WPF or Silverlight? I recall seeing another question here on SO where text was missing with Silverlight in an IE9 beta (can't find it now, though).

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to examine your visual tree. I suspect the text is there but its foreground color makes it invisible.

Comment: I replaced the above XAML code snippet with the following one in my XAML file to set the background and foreground colors of the control:

Comment: <RadioButton Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="RadioButton1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="15" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Blue">

    C# Corner

</RadioButton>

Comment: But still is the same issue of the Content text not being displayed at runtime

Comment: As Jason said, perhaps you're changing the Content property in code-behind... Or perhaps you defined an implicit style for RadioButtons, and the template doesn't include the content.